# Theming, Layout & Design Questions

Tags: layout

I am using Magento 1922 with a custom theme. By default Magento comes with 4 Store Views: English, German, Spanish, Russian). I created a new store view named French/french, it has a language set up. When I switch in frontend the language to French the whole layout gets nuts. In backend all store views have the same options in Web section, all coming from Default Config. French has them too, but something makes it not working as expected. In order to fix this I had to fill in the Layout input box in Default Config.

Question: Why those 4 Store Views are displaying great and getting correctly the layout without being specified (only package, templates and skin are filled in as value) and this new store, which has the same values, is not working without having layout filled in.

Comment: I would make sure you flush the caches, make sure you do not have any server side caches enabled that need to be flushed like opcache.

Comment: Well everything was flushed after the changes. The only way to deal with this was to set up in System -> Configuration -> General -> Design -> Layout input box the layout name of the theme. I really don't understand how can 4 Store Views working great by default without this layout filled in and when I create a new Store View I am forced to fill in the theme layout.